# Needed to fill in the questions for URI path, controller, and the action/method after I place in routes commands, but I wasn't sure want to look for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The pertinent line in the output from the rails routes command for dealing with listing all articles is as follows:

articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index

The URI path to your new view in the above line is _____________.

The controller is  ___________.

The action or method in the above controller is _____________

*********OUTPUT FROM BASH COMMAND************************

`ec2-user:~/environment/ruby_labs/blog (master) $ rails routes
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
            welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)                                                                 welcome#index
             new_articles GET    /articles/new(.:format)                                                                  articles#new
            edit_articles GET    /articles/edit(.:format)                                                                 articles#edit
                 articles GET    /articles(.:format)                                                                      articles#show
                          PATCH  /articles(.:format)                                                                      articles#update
                          PUT    /articles(.:format)                                                                      articles#update
                          DELETE /articles(.:format)                                                                      articles#destroy
                          POST   /articles(.:format)                                                                      articles#create
                     root GET    /                                                                                        welcome#index
                  article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                                                                  articles#show
                          GET    /articles(.:format)                                                                      articles#index
       rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
     rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create`

Answer (score 0):

The question above reviews rails conventions and file structure.
You can learn more about it here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/routing.html

**The answers to above the questions would be the following:**

- The URI path to your new view in the above line is `/articles/index`
- The controller is `articles_controller`
- The action or method in the above controller is `#index`